# JQuery - Refresh Div With Data, Not Working with IE

Tags: jquery, html

Updated .....

I am new with JQuery and I am stuck on this and hoping someone can help me. What I am trying to do is refresh the data in the DIV without reload entire page. The because the page is huge, I am trying to summarize this.

```
--- This form is right after the body, not wrab with DIV or anything, no submit button.  I want to submit the value in the textbox when user hit ENTER key.

<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="PurchaseRequestList.asp">
    <input type="text" name="CompanyName" id="CompanyName" value=""  class="box2">
</form>
--- Below the form is the  DIVs, where I like to refresh the data everytime user enter in the CompanyName textbox and hit Enter key.

<div id="div1-wrapper">
    <div id="div1" style="border:solid 1px red; width: 100%;"> 
        <table width="90%" align="center" class="RowDetail">
            <--  This is where the loop using ASP to display the data -->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far, I have this code, but it is not working as refresh only data within the DIV.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#CompanyName').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var data =  $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            data: data,
            url: 'PurchaseRequestList.asp?#div1',
            success: function(res) {
                $('#div1-wrapper').load(url + ' #div1'); 
            }
        });
    }
    });
});
```

I appreciated you guys are trying to help. Let me know if you need me to clarify any.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
var url = 'PurchaseRequestList.asp?order=1';  
  $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var data =  $( this ).serialize();
   $.ajax({
     method: 'post',
     data: data,
     url: url  + '?#div1',
     success: function(res) {
       $('#div1-wrapper').load(res);//u need to change here 
    }
  });
 });
```

or

```
  $('#CompanyName').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var data =  $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            data: data,
            url: url  + '?#div1',
            success: function(res) {
                $('#div1-wrapper').load(res); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: wat the problem with it?

Comment: I tried both, it reload entire page instead of just the DIV1. Sorry, I must doing something wrong here.

Comment: try the second one by removing all other code. You need to remove the form submittng code also